# How to safely access other users and other model's records inside Blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have 3 models in my app Users, Sales and Plans, when I render sales for each customer (due to storing) I only get id's for other users and models related to that sale (like account manager, owner, plan), now I'm trying to use those ID's inside blade to get names or other rows based on ID and model. Here is the show function:

```
public function show($id) {
$user = User::find($id);
$sales = Sale::where('customer_id', '=', $id)->get();
return view('profiles.customer', ['user' => $user, 'sales' => $sales]);
}
```

And in blade I get all those sales like:

```
@foreach ($sales as $sale)
    <li>
        <i class="fa fa-home bg-blue"></i>
        <div class="timeline-item">
            <span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{$sale->created_at->format('g:ia, M jS Y')}}</span>

            <h3 class="timeline-header"><a href="#">{{$user->name}}</a> became a customer</h3>

            <div class="timeline-body">
                <p>Date: {{$sale->sold_date}}</p>
                <p>Price: {{$sale->sale_price}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

So inside each record I have like "account_manager_id", "agent_id", "owner_id", "plan_id".

Currently I have this solved by adding public static function (this is for users, have same function for Plan model as well) in Sale model class:

```
public static function getUser($id) {
    return User::where('id', $id)->first();
}
```

And I'm using it like this in Blade:

```
Account manager: {{$sale->getUser($sale->account_mgr_id)->name}}
```

Is this the safest and best way to do it? Or there is something I'm overlooking here?

Comment: How did you manage Relationship in Sales Model?

Comment: Well that's the might be a problem, I don't have relations set up, didn't know quite how to get it since each sales model record has 5 different users and one plan model id...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add relationships in your Sales Model.

```
class Sales extends Eloquent {

    .....
    .....

    public function accountManager() {
         return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'account_manager_id');
    }

    public function agents() {
         return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'agent_id');
    }

    public function owner() {
         return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'owner_id');
    }
}
```

Now `$sales->agents` will give you a user with `agent_id` as `id` in `User` table.

Update your `hasOne`, `hasMany` relationships as your need. [Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships).

From your blade template, your access your AccountManager as

```
@foreach($sales->accountManager as $manager)
  Name: {{ $manager->name}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: This is the closest but this way it's searching for account_manager_id inside the User tables and it should be searching for id based on account_manager_id in Sales table.

Comment: OK, i just added 'id' for example now its ('App\User', 'id', 'agent_id'); so it works now. Thanks man!!!

Comment: Check the documentation 'return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');'. Hope you'll be able to solve.

Comment: LOL, we answered same thing at the same time... Anyway I changed hasMany to hasOne and return it without foreach in blade (since every sale has only one of each of these id's)

Comment: @Dino Happy Coding ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use [Eloquent relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships). Taking your example, you should define relationship in your User model:

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent {
    public function sales() {
         return $this->hasMany(Sale::class, 'customer_id');
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you need to get sales of that user (entries, that relate via customer_id column), just simply do

```
<?php

$user = User::find($id);
$sales = $user->sales;
```

This is very fun when when you have to print out list of users that have sales, for example

```
<?php

public function showUsersWithSales() {
    $users = User::with('sales')->get();

    return view('users-with-sales', compact('users'));
}
```

users-with-sales.blade.php example:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    User: {{ $user->name }}<br>
    Sales:<br>
    @foreach ($user->sales as $sale)
        {{ $sale->amount }} {{ $sale->currency }} @ {{ $sale->created_at }}<br>
    @endforeach
    <hr>
@endforeach
```

It would print all users with their sale amount and currency, followed by date when it was created.
This sample takes into account, that your User model has name attribute and your Sale model has amount, currency, created_at and customer_id fields in your database.

To reverse the action, say you have a sale and want to know who made it, just simply define a relationship!

```
<?php

class Sale extends Eloquent {
    public function customer() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'customer_id');
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Eloquent Relationship is your friend, https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships and you can solve your problem easily.

Suggestion is to remove all those function access and control from view and put it somewhere else. This will be good habit for you so you can avoid the infamous **fat view**.

Comment: Other answer gave me solution, but can you elaborate more on that "fat view" so I can avoid it?

Comment: Basically you need to remember that less is better in the world of programming, if you can solve a problem with less effort yet still responsible enough, the less is the best practice.

Fat view is when your view in MVC paradigm got lot of control structure and function that it become hard to maintain and detached from M and C counterpart. 

Control structure such as if else, and function is better to be represented as state. And you can take all of that code to the controller or the class that is more responsible.